# @Html.DisplayFor for Empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display empty string when `model.EndDate` is `0`

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => model.EndDate)
```

I tried

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => model.EndDate == 0 ? "" : model.EndDate.ToString())
```

and

```
@Html.Display("End Date",model.EndDate == 0 ? "" : model.EndDate.ToString())
```

both did not worked for me. Both of the displaying empty when data is available.

Comment: How can a date be 0? Or is this an integer field?

Comment: @James123 ***Just FYI: please never ever name integer field as EndDate. You can see the answers below how people get confuse. It'll also come back and bite you after six months or so.***

Comment: @Win you mean: "It'll come back and bite you after 186 or so".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a conditional outside the `DisplayFor`:

```
@if (Model.EndDate != 0)
{
    Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => model.EndDate)
}
```

Comment: You can also use a custom Display Template for your data type (which you haven't said what the type really is). Ideally, nullable data types are the best way to go because they don't start with a default value (0 for a number and DateTime.MinValue for a date). That being said, if your using an int data type you may not want a custom Display Template because you may want to treat ints differently in different places.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a datetime to 0 in asp.net.

```
error CS0019: Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type `System.DateTime' and `int'
```

A DateTime is a value type so it get a default value of DateTime.MinValue when it isn't set.

```
using System;
public class Test {
    public static DateTime badDate;
    public static DateTime goodDate = DateTime.Now; 
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(goodDate == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : goodDate.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(badDate == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : badDate.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make your model property be a nullable type. So for example if its type is DateTime then declare the property as a nullable DateTime:

```
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

this way instead of a 0 date (whatever that means) you will have no value. This also makes sense especially if this model property is coming from the database and is nullable.

You can read more about the nullable types here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about this one ?

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse("Your Date", out dt))
{
    //Now you have validated the date
    //Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like the answers given above because adding IF Statements to everything just slows your system down, in my case i needed to display a default string value several times in each row of a list view when the class property was a null value.

So have a look at the MS Docs here:
[DisplayFormatAttribute.NullDisplayText Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.nulldisplaytext?view=net-5.0)

*The following example shows how to use the NullDisplayText to define a caption to display when the data field is null.*

```
// Display the text [Null] when the data field is empty.
// Also, convert empty string to null for storing.
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText = "[Null]")]
public object Size;
```